# Simple Chat with RMI - how the server can stop execution of all clients without launching remote exception

Tags: java, chat, rmi

I have a problem with my Java RMI chat (client-server type) in which clients  can "subscribe to the server", meaning all client refs are stored in an ArrayList on the server, all clients can access to specific commands and one client in turn can be a "special" client.

All commands respond in a different way depending if a client is the "special" or not (simply the server chooses one client and target it as "special" storing his reference in the ArrayList as normal and plus in a variable called `active`), in particular I have a problem with the command !quit:

If a special client calls the cmd !quit, he calls the remote method on the server `siesce(Client reference)` and then the server removes ALL REFERENCES of ALL CLIENTS from the ArrayList and calls back the `abbandona()` on ALL CLIENTS after which they should stop their execution.

**Client Implementation variables**

```
public class ClientImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Client {
...
private static Server server;        //reference to server
private static ClientImpl client;    //reference to client object (it-self)
...
```

**Client Method abbandona()**

```
public void abbandona() throws RemoteException {         
        System.out.println("Sei stato espulso dalla chat");
        System.exit(0);   
}
```

**Client main**

Client inserts cmd !quit that calls this portion of code

```
//start of main and objects creations
...
try {
    server.siesce(client);
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    System.out.println("Esco...");
    System.exit(1);
}
//end of main
```

**Server Implementation variables**

```
public class ServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Server{
...
private static ArrayList<Persona> cli = new ArrayList<Persona>();
       //the Persona object is a wrapper that contains a Client reference and a boolean
       //the client can be taken by calling getCli()
...
private static Client active;  //reference to SPECIAL client
```

**Server method siesce(Client ref)**

```
public synchronized void siesce(Client ref) throws RemoteException {
        if (ref.equals(active)) {            //checks if the SPECIAL client called this method
            for (int i=0; i<cli.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    cli.get(i).getCli().abbandona();   
                    logger.info("...");                
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    logger.severe("...");
                }       
            }                           
            cli.clear();          //variables reset
            count = 0;
            guard = 0;
            active = null;
            ready = false;                               
        }
        else {               //this else is used when a normal client calls this method
             ...
        }

    }
...
```

The problem is the fact that in the loop that checks all ArrayList elements after the first `cli.get(i).getCli().abbandona()` is called on the first element it launches the RemoteException (because the client quits) which is caught in the MAIN code of the client and not in the try catch in the for loop and this stops the method from continue doing this on other elements, so only the first client quits when the others don't.

How can achieve to let all clients stop their execution?

Answer (score 0):

The client shouldn't exit inside the callback. Instead it should just (a) unexport itself and (b) post a Boolean somewhere that will tell the main thread to exit, after a couple of seconds to allow the callback to complete.